Flipping bits with probability $1-p$, how large can $p$ get?
Let's say I have an n-bit string, where I flip any bit with probability $1-p$. Call the uncorrupted string $\mathbf{b} = (b_1,...,b_n)$, and the corrupted one $\tilde{\mathbf{b}} = (\tilde{b}_1,..)$. Now define the "bit-flip" distance between $\mathbf{b}$ and $\tilde{\mathbf{b}}$ with:
\begin{align*}
     X = || \mathbf{b} - \tilde{\mathbf{b}} ||_1.
\end{align*}
I want the expected value of $X$ to be less than some value $d$ where $d = 0,1,2,..$. So we have:
\begin{align*}
     E[X] = \sum_{x=1}^n x\binom{n}{x}  p^{n-x} (1-p)^x = n(1-p).
\end{align*}
And note this expected value is correct, see Expected Value of a Binomial distribution?.
So we solve for $p$ and have:
\begin{align*}
     n(1-p) \leq d \implies p \geq 1 - \frac{d}{n}.
\end{align*}
So if we set constraint where $\mathbf{b}$ and $\tilde{\mathbf{b}}$ do not differ in more than 10% of the bits, then say $d=10$ and $n=100$. Then this means $p \geq 1 - 0.10 = 0.90$. This places a very high constraint on the value of $p$. Am I missing something here?

Can you go more into why you think that's confusing? You want at least 90% of the bits to be correct, so the probability of not flipping should be at least 90%? Also I should note that in the title you say that the probability of flipping is $p$, but in your first sentence the probability of flipping is $1 - p$.

@S.C. fixed. Yves Daoust , it make sense intuitively, but I was somewhat disappointed by the triviality of the result.
